# changing service accounts password - powershell way

Tags: 2013, powershell, service-account, password

I have about 10 service accounts for SharePoint 2013. Is there a good PowerShell script that I can use to change the password for all of these accounts? I have seen this http://www.mstechbits.com/sharepoint-2013/how-to-change-service-account-password-in-sharepoint-2013/ but this is manual and there is no way to do this efficiently for 20 SharePoint servers (prod, test, dev and QC).

Comment: are those managed accounts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below mentioned script on each farm.

```
$mc = Get-SPManagedAccount
foreach($acc in $mc)
{
 Set-SPManagedAccount -Identity $acc  -ExistingPassword (ConvertTo-SecureString “pass@word2” -AsPlainText -force) –confirm
}
```

But drawback is all accounts will have the same password.check this technet for more options: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607617.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Another way is to schedule automatic password change at central admin.

Comment: I am okay with the same password. will it change the password in Active Directory?

Comment: it will not, it will only update the SharePoint with password.

Comment: for that try to use -AutoGeneratePassword true also check this option SetNewPassword

Comment: Note that -AutoGeneratePassword will only work if the account does not have 'never expire password' and 'user cannot change password' set.

Comment: new for me, as we always use existing options...

Comment: I guess I can use Set-ADAccountPassword (http://blog.simonw.se/reset-password-in-active-directory-using-powershell) to change AD password then I will use Waqas's method to change SharePoint password.

Comment: see this http://blogs.interfacett.com/using-powershell-reset-active-directory-passwords-bulk

Comment: have you tried the setnewpassword option?

Comment: This code works. Thanks all for the support and ideas. $cPassword= ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Summer@2016' -AsPlainText -Force
$nPassword= ConvertTo-SecureString -String 'Winter@2016' -AsPlainText -Force
Set-ADAccountPassword -Identity testacct11 -OldPassword $cPassword -NewPassword $nPassword

Comment: kool, things are working for you.

Comment: in production i had to change the app pool password manually. it's super pain in rare.